# Unable to send an email after clicking on submit button in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Trying to send an email not displaying any error message or anything just refreshing the page that it.

I am trying an email through contact form but its not working.Here is the code for that. tried by doing echo but it is not working .not displaying any error as well.

contact and contactus:

```
<?php ob_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$txt = $_POST['comment'];
$headers = "From: " .$email . "\r\n" .
"CC: xyz@gmail.com";    
mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);   
header("Location: contact.php");    
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HMS System</title>       
</head>
<body>      
    <div class="container">         
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Contact Us Form</h2>
                </div>
                <form class="form-horizontal" action="contactus.php" method="post" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Insert your Name" id="name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email Address</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" id="subject">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comments" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Comment</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" name="comment" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send Message" name="submit_contact" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" id="subject">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </section>

        </article>
    </div>
    <div style="width:50px;height:50px;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Use error_reporting (E_ALL); on top to display existing errors

Comment: @Michael not displaying any errors just refreshing the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_contact']))
```

Comment: Added redirect to contact.php page not getting any message

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it from your local server, you will have to setup your mail properly in ini then only you will be able to send mail from your local machine.

Comment: No i am trying in live server this is my website app.sarastek.website In this contact us page

Comment: Did you check your spam?

Comment: Gmail verifies the received mails against the server they were sent from for being actual or masked. Example if you are sending mails from your server and using a gmail account in to, it will notify the user that the mail wasn't sent from gmail servers. It might even flag it as spam. Better way would be using SMTP to send mails.

Comment: put mail in an if statement and see if it returns true. if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers)) echo "Mail Sent";

Comment: Not getting anything

Comment: Then your mail is disabled. You need to configure your ini to enable mail.

Comment: how can we do that can you explain

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit_contact'])) 
 {  
  $to = "abc@gmail.com,hai@gmail.com";
  $name = $_POST['name'];        
         $email = $_POST['email']; 
         $subject = $_POST['subject'];        
         $comment = $_POST['comment'];       
         $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$comment);    
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
 header("Location: contact.php");
 }  i have added this cde it is working fine but from address is website hosting one how can we can change that

Comment: mail ($to,$subject,$comment, "From : email@mail.com");

Comment: That will set the from mail

Comment: if we want to add cc then

Comment: Its not working adding like that displaying the server email only

Comment: $headers = 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail ($to,$subject,$comment, $headers);

Comment: from address should be the address which user enters in contact form

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to wrap the `mail` function in a statement. Mail is returning a `bool` value. *And beginn as simple as possible.*

```
error_reporting (E_ALL);

$to = "mail@whatever.com"
// ... your settings ...

if ( mail ( $to , $subject , $message ) ) {

    // do when ok

} 
else {  

    // do when error

}
```

To verify that you receive all values from `$_POST` do

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```